# How to access property of inner object in ES6 if properties of outer object are dynamic?

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6

I have following object -:

```
const response = { 'ALICE': { CLUSTER:'3', ... } }
```

How i can access property `CLUSTER` ?.   The `response` object is coming from server and the outer key i.e `'ALICE'` here is unknown, it can be any possible name, but value i.e `{CLUSTER: '3', ...}` has fixed properties.

Comment: like `Object.values(response)[0].CLUSTER...` ?

Comment: ```Object.values(response)```

Answer (score 0):

Just map over the keys in your object, e.g.

```
Object.keys(response).map((key: string) => {
  const alice = response[key];
  alice["CLUSTER"]...
});
```

If you use typescript, you could define it even better, as a map from string as key and your final type as inner object.

Answer (score 0):

If the outer objects property name is unknown, you will need to loop over the response object and test if there is a `CLUSTER` property inside.

```js
const test1 = { 'ALICE': { CLUSTER: 1 } }
const test2 = { 'LOREM': { CLUSTER: 2 } }
const test3 = { 'IPSUM': { CLUSTER: 3 } }

// logs 1
for (const value of Object.values(test1)) {
   if (value.CLUSTER) {
      console.log(value.CLUSTER)
   }
}

// logs 2
for (const value of Object.values(test2)) {
   if (value.CLUSTER) {
      console.log(value.CLUSTER)
   }
}

// logs 3
for (const value of Object.values(test3)) {
   if (value.CLUSTER) {
      console.log(value.CLUSTER)
   }
}
```

This logic does not handle the case if you have multiple outer objects that contain `CLUSTER`, but you can easily add extra checks yourself.